# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.unzip(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/io/File;

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to run selenium webdriver program, getting following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.unzip(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/io/File;
```

Firefox version : 47.0.1
Selenium version : 2.53.1
Eclipse : Oxygen Release (4.7.0)

```
import org.apache.xpath.XPathContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class PG1 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/newtours/");
            System.out.println("The title of page is : " + driver.getTitle());
            driver.close();
        }
    }
```

This program was working fine in another laptop, but not working on new laptop/setup.

Can someone please help.

Error I'm getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.unzip(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/io/File;
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.obtainRootDirectory(FileExtension.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.writeTo(FileExtension.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ClasspathExtension.writeTo(ClasspathExtension.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.installExtensions(FirefoxProfile.java:443)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:421)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startClient(RemoteWebDriver.java:303)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at bitbfw.PG1.main(PG1.java:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found what was wrong.. 
it was that in "Java Build Path", the JRE system library was not added earlier. I went to configure Build path-->Add Jars selected "jRE system library", Applied & Closed.

Then on all the programs worked fine.